# Excel FormulaR1C1 and FormulaArray

Tags: arrays, excel, dynamic, range, formula

I have the following table setup in Excel. I am looking to fill the remainder of the table with the array formula that I have successfully trialed in Column B.

[image]

The code below autofills the table, but not with an array formula, merely with the formula, so it does not return the required result. How do I change it so that the array formula is propogated?

Note that the number of Users & Courses does change hence the dynamic calculation of the range is a fixed requirement.

```
Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B3", Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).FormulaR1C1 Range("B3").FormulaR1C1
```

Comment: You could put all of the array formula in at once. Alternately, use VBA's [Range.FillDown method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx) and [Range.FillRight method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837984.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Edit, since it didn't work as intended.
There two other method i would use.
First, the most obvious, is the range `.AutoFill` method:

```
Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B3", Cells(3, LastCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B3", Cells(3, LastCol)).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B3", Cells(LastRow, LastCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Which works fine, you can easily control how the formulas will look like.
The other option is to iterate through all cells in your range and just copy the formula, though it just copies the formula as is, with all references to original lookup cell and I doubt it's what your'e looking for, but here it is nevertheless:

```
Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To LastRow
    For j = 2 To LastCol
        Cells(i, j).FormulaArray = Cells(3, 2).FormulaArray
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: When I use .FormulaR1C1 then as the formula is propogated across the range the Column & Row values change accordingly, as would be seen in a copy / paste function. However when I replace .FormulaR1C1 with .FormulaArray the Column & Row values that propogate remain the same as if I had used a $A$1 type functionality to freeze the source.

Any ideas as to why that is, or howto resolve??

Comment: Here is my array formula :-

=INDEX(Working!$A$5:$R$5000,MATCH(1,(Working!$A$5:$A$5000=$A7)*(Working!$D$5:$D$5000=E$2),0),18)

Comment: If you don't mind waiting couple of hours, I'll see what's happening. Unless there's another answer that works.
What I'd try is iterate through each cell istead of assigning formula to the whole range

Comment: Please find the post updated. Sorry for taking my time and I hope that helps if you're still looking for answer. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dani El.

Answer (score 0):

Answer that works for me :-

```
Range("B3").Copy

Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'Range ("C3:F12")
Range("C3", Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get it to work.........

```
Range("B3").Copy

Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Range("C3", Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```